# Deriving 'State-Action marginal' in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I see the following equation1 in "In Reinforcement Learning Course CS294". I want to prove "1 equation is same 2 equation."

[image: equation1]

I tried but failed :( What's wrong..?

[image: mySolve]

Answer (score 1):

$$
  p_\theta(\tau) = p_\theta(s_0, (s_1, a_1), ..., (s_t, a_t))
$$
is the distribution over all trajectories, which could also be seen as the joint distribution over all states and actions under the policy. Thus,
$$
  \text{E}_{\tau \sim p_\theta(\tau)}[r(s_t, a_t)] = \text{E}_{(s_t, a_t) \sim p_\theta(\tau)}[r(s_t, a_t)] = \text{E}_{(s_t, a_t) \sim p_\theta(s_t, a_t)}[r(s_t, a_t)],
$$
where $(s_t, a_t) \sim p_\theta(\tau)$ could be seen as the probability of $(s_t, a_t)$ occurring, no matter which trajectory was taken to get there since it's not relevant here.

The expression
$$
    \text{E}_{(s_t, a_t) \sim p_\theta(s_t, a_t \mid s_{t-1}, a_{t-a} )}[r(s_t, a_t)]
$$
is the *conditional expectation* of  the reward at time $t$ given the state and action in time $t-1$, which is a different entity. This would be interesting when asking questions such as *what is the expected return of the next time-step if the current state and action is* $(s_t, a_t)$. A more rigorous way of looking at it is
$$
  \text{E}_{\tau \sim p_\theta}\left[\sum_{t=1}^T r(s_t, a_t)\right] = \sum_{\tau}p_\theta(\tau)\sum_{t=1}^T r(s_t, a_t) = \sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{\tau} p_\theta(\tau)r(s_t, a_t) = \sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{u=1}^{t-1}r(s_t, a_t)p_\theta\left(s_t, a_t \mid s_0, \{s_k, a_k\}_{k=1}^u\right)p_\theta\left(s_0, \{s_k, a_k\}_{k=1}^u\right) = \sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{u=1}^{t-1}p_\theta\left(s_0, \{s_k, a_k\}_{k=1}^u\right)\text{E}[r(s_t, a_t) \mid \pi_\theta, s_0, \{s_k, a_k\}_{k=1}^u] = \sum_{t=1}^T\text{E}_{(s_t, a_t)\sim p_\theta(s_t, a_t)}[r(s_t, a_t)].
$$

This answer about the [linearity of expectation for dependent variables in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1810371) could help shining some light on the matter.

Comment: Does anybody verify emarcus' answer to be correct? I think he/she missed a sum in the second line that states equations and and the initial state is $\mathbf{s}_1$ rather than $\mathbf{s}_0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to rephrase the second and more rigorous part of emarcus' answer in more detail. We start by assuming that probability over a trajectory $\tau$ factorizes like
$$p_\theta(\tau)=p_\theta(s_1,a_1,\ldots,s_T,a_T)=
p(s_1)\pi_\theta(a_1|s_1)\prod_{t=1}^Tp(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t)\pi_\theta(a_{t+1}|s_{t+1})=\\
p_\theta(s_1,a_1)\prod_{t=1}^Tp_\theta(s_{t+1},a_{t+1}|s_t,a_t)
$$
assuming the graphical model of a Markov decision process and following the notation from Sergey Levine's deepRL course CS285 (although there it for some reason says that $p_\theta(\tau)=p(s_1)\prod_{t=1}^Tp(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t)\pi_\theta(a_{t}|s_{t})$ so $\tau$ theoretically ends with $s_1,a_1\ldots s_T,a_T,s_{T+1}$).
Now we can expand the expectation assuming continuous random variables
$$
E_{\tau\sim p_\theta(\tau)}[\sum_{t=1}^Tr(s_t,a_t) ]= \int p_\theta(\tau) \sum_{t=1}^Tr(s_t,a_t)d\tau=\sum_{t=1}^T\int p_\theta(\tau)r(s_t,a_t)d\tau
$$
where we used the linearity property of the expectation operator. Inserting the result above leads to
$$
=\sum_{t=1}^T\int p_\theta(s_1,a_1)\prod_{k=1}^Tp_\theta(s_{k+1},a_{k+1}|s_k,a_k)r(s_t,a_t)d\tau
$$
Since each summand depends only on terms from $1$ to $t$, we can further simplify
$$ 
=\sum_{t=1}^T\int p_\theta(s_1,a_1)\prod_{k=2}^{t}p_\theta(s_{k},a_{k}|s_{k-1},a_{k-1})r(s_t,a_t)d\{s_k,a_k\}_{k=1}^t
$$
We now realize that $p_\theta(s_1,a_1)\prod_{k=2}^{t}p_\theta(s_{k},a_{k}|s_{k-1},a_{k-1})=p(\{s_k,a_k\}_{k=1}^t)$ so
$$ 
=\sum_{t=1}^T\int p(\{s_k,a_k\}_{k=1}^t)r(s_t,a_t)d\{s_k,a_k\}_{k=1}^t
$$
and use $E_{(x,y)\sim p(x,y)}[x]=\int p(x,y)xdxdy=\int x\int p(x,y)dy dx=\int xp(x)dx=E_{x\sim p(x)}[x]$, we arrive at
$$
=\sum_{t=1}^T\int r(s_t,a_t) \int p(\{s_k,a_k\}_{k=1}^t)d\{s_k,a_k\}_{k=1}^{t-1}ds_t da_t\\=\sum_{t=1}^T\int p(s_t,a_t)r(s_t,a_t)ds_t da_t= \sum_{t=1}^TE_{(s_t,a_t)\sim p(s_t,a_t)}[r(s_t,a_t)]
$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed derivation. This is really helpful!